# OWASP ZAP security using azure devops classic pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, owasp, zap

[image: screenshot of powershell failure]

https://dzone.com/articles/owasp-zap-security-tests-in-azure-devops-pipeline this is the reference article we are using.

while executing the PowerShell script we are getting error

this is the PowerShell script we are using

```
$XslPath = "$($Env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY)/_CodeShare/securitytesting/OWASPToNUnit3.xslt"
$XmlInputPath = "$($Env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY)/OWASP-ZAP-Report.xml"
$XmlOutputPath = "$($Env:SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY)/Converted-OWASP-ZAP-Report.xml"
$XslTransform = New-Object System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform
$XslTransform.Load($XslPath)
$XslTransform.Transform($XmlInputPath, $XmlOutputPath)
```

Comment: Seems it can't find the file OWASPToNUnit3.xslt at the location you're pointing to. Did you follow the instructions regarding downloading that file to the correct location in the reference article?

Comment: yes even i have not downloaded the file i have imported the same repo in my personal azure repo

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not share images of code and/or errors. Instead, copy and paste them here. You should do this since it is impossible to debug screenshots.